# Convert exponential number to Decimal using shell

Tags: shell, decimal, exponential

I have an exponential number and I want to convert it to decimal.

Here is my sample value

```
5.7711608E7
```

Above is memory value of EC2 machine which is in KB format.

How do I convert above value to decimal using shell script?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{print 5.7711608E7}'` maybe

Comment: `perl -e 'print 5.7711608E13'` maybe

Comment: @MarkSetchell Both awk and perl command are working and producing the same output for my exponential input..